# Hummingbird DM5- Does DM5 API supports multithreading?

Tags: multithreading, c#-4.0, dll, document-management

Does Hummingbird dm5 api supports multithreadig?
I have been using following api as a com component:
1. DECoreLib.dll
2. DOCSObjects.dll
3. DECoreLib.dll